# Getting Error 10001

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {

    Map<Id,Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
    List<Projected_Opportunity__c> PoList = new List<Projected_Opportunity__c>();
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
            if(o.Contract_Term__c!= null){
                OppMap.put(o.Id,o);
            }
        }
        if(OppMap.Size()>0){
            System.debug('OppMap'+OppMap);

            for(Opportunity opps : OppMap.values()){
                for(Integer i=0; i< opps.Contract_Term__c; i++){
                    Projected_Opportunity__c  po = new Projected_Opportunity__c();
                    po.Opportunity__c = opps.Id; 
                    po.Opportunity_Name__c = opps.Name; 
                    po.Stage__c = opps.StageName;
                    po.Probability__c = opps.Probability;
                    po.Closed_Date__c = opps.CloseDate;
                    po.Month_No__c = opps.Month_No__c;
                    po.Projected_Implementation_Date__c = opps.Implementation_Date__c.addMonths(i);
                    po.Contract_Term__c=opps.Contract_Term__c;
                    po.Amount__c = opps.Amount;
                    po.Monthly_Projected_Revenue__c = opps.Projected_Revenue_1__c;
                    po.Target_Revenue__c = opps.Q1RF_target__c;
                    po.Total_Project_Revenue__c = opps.Total_Project_Revenue__c;
                PoList.add(po);
                }
            }
            insert PoList;
            System.debug('PoList'+PoList);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to check if you're approaching your limit of 10,000 rows, and then decide what to do in that scenario. You're limited to 10,000 rows worth of create/updates in code, so if there's more than 10,000 months (~833 years), you will need to switch to another context (Queueable or Batchable) to complete the tabulation of your data.

While 833 years seems like a long time, it really only takes 200 records with 60 month contracts to blow past this governor limit. Here's an example implementation of this idea to get you started.

---

## Class: OpportunityBuildPO

```
public class OpportunityBuildPO implements Queueable {
    Opportunity[] records;
    public OpportunityBuildPO(Opportunity[] records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        buildPOs(records);
        if(!records.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }
    public static void buildPOs(Opportunity[] opps) {
        Integer totalCount = 0, totalLimit = Limits.getLimitDmlRows() - Limits.getDmlRows();
        List<Projected_Opportunity__c> PoList = new List<Projected_Opportunity__c>();
        
        for(Integer i = opps.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Opportunity o = opps[i];
            if(totalCount + o.Contract_Term__c < totalLimit) {
                totalCount += o.Contract_Term__c;
                opps.remove(i);
                Projected_Opportunity__c  template = new Projected_Opportunity__c(
                    Opportunity__c = o.Id,
                    Opportunity_Name__c = o.Name,
                    Stage__c = o.StageName,
                    Probability__c = o.Probability,
                    Closed_Date__c = o.CloseDate,
                    Month_No__c = o.Month_No__c,
                    Contract_Term__c=o.Contract_Term__c,
                    Amount__c = o.Amount,
                    Monthly_Projected_Revenue__c = o.Projected_Revenue_1__c,
                    Target_Revenue__c = o.Q1RF_target__c,
                    Total_Project_Revenue__c = o.Total_Project_Revenue__c);
                for(Integer i = 0; i < o.Contract_Term__c; i++) {
                    Projected_Opportunity__c temp = template.clone();
                    temp.Projected_Implementation_Date__c = opps.Implementation_Date__c.addMonths(i);
                    PoList.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        insert PoList;
    }
}
```

---

## Trigger: OppTrigger

```
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
    Opportunity[] opps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Contract_Term__c != null && record.Implementation_Date__c != null) {
            opps.add(record);
        }
    }
    OpportunityBuildPO.buildPOs(opps);
    if(!opps.isEmpty()) {
        System.enqueueJob(new OpportunityBuildPO(opps));
    }
}
```

---